# Codeigniter ajax(jquery) login session issue?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i m new in Codeigniter and i have created a Login system with jquery in codeigniter. but i m stuck with the session problem. When i will submit the login from i will works perfectly and create the session perfectly but when it will redirect to the next page after login the session will destroyed automatically and it will come back to the login page all the time.

Can any one help to what to do in that??
My code is below

Admin Controller

```
    <?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
    function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Admin Panel';
        $this->load->helper('auth');
        if(is_admin_loggedin(0)){ // Check if is login 
            //To display Dashboard Page
            $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
        }else{
            //To display Login Page
            $this->load->view('admin/login/index', $data);
        }
    }

    function login_action(){
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $query = $this->login_model->check_login();
        if($query){
            $data = array(
                'adminid' => $query[0]['AdminID'],
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            print_r($this->session);
            exit;
            //redirect('admin');
            $success = true;
            $success_redirect = true;
            $success_msg = site_url('admin');
            $error = false;
            $error_msg = '';            
        }else{
            $success = false;
            $success_redirect = false;
            $success_msg = site_url('admin');
            $error = true;
            $error_msg = 'Error, Wrong username or password!';
        }
        $passstring = array(
            'success' => $success,
            'success_msg' => $success_msg,
            'success_redirect' => $success_redirect,
            'error' => $error,
            'error_msg' => $error_msg
        );

        echo json_encode($passstring);
    }
}
?>
```

i have created the auth helper file for checking the login is set or not.

auth_helper.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('is_admin_loggedin'))
{
    function is_admin_loggedin($reval){
        // Get current CodeIgniter instance
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // We need to use $CI->session instead of $this->session
        $adminid = $CI->session->userdata('adminid');
        $is_logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if($reval == 1){
            return $CI->session;
        }else{
            if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true || !isset($adminid) || $adminid != '')
            {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

login_model.php

```
<?php
class Login_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function check_login(){
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'trim|required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        //if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->db->where('UserName', $this->input->post('username'));
            $this->db->where('Password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
            $this->db->select('AdminID');
            $query = $this->db->get('admin');
            if($query->num_rows == 1)
            {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        //}
    }
}
?>
```

My view file Code

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/login_action" method="post" name="LoginAdmin" id="LoginAdmin" >
                        <div class="error-container hide"></div>
                        <div class="login-box-row-wrap corners">
                            <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" id="username" value="" name="username" class="input-1"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-box-row-wrap corners">
                            <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" value="" name="password" class="input-1 password"/>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-box-row corners">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="field-remember"/> <label for="field-remember">Remember me?</label>
                            <input type="submit" name="submitfrm" value="Login" id="submit"/>
                        </div>
                        </form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var LoginID = '#LoginAdmin';
        $(LoginID).submit(function(){
        var errorselector = LoginID+' .error-container';
        $(errorselector).html('').hide();
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var paossword = $('#password').val();
        var isValid = 0;
        var errmsg = '';
        if(!checkblank(username) || !checkblank(paossword)){
            errmsg = 'Please fill all the fields.';
            isValid = 1;
        }
        if(isValid == 0){
            $('.loader').show();
            var urlred = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlred,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg){
                    console.log(msg);
                    $('.loader').hide();
                    if (msg.success == false && msg.error == true) {
                        if(msg.error_msg != ''){
                            errormsg = msg.error_msg;
                        }else{
                            errormsg = 'Error, Something Worong';
                        }
                        $msgdis = '<div class="login-box-error-small corners"><p>'+errormsg+'</p></div>';
                        $(errorselector).html($msgdis).slideDown('slow');
                    }else if (msg.success == true && msg.error == false) {
                        if(msg.success_redirect == true){
                            window.location = msg.success_msg;
                        }else{
                            $msgdis = '<div class="login-box-succes-small corners"><p>'+msg.success_msg+'</p></div>';
                            $(errorselector).html($msgdis).slideDown('slow');
                        }
                    }
                    $(this).find('button.submitbutton').attr('disabled', '');
                },
                error: function(){
                    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar #ui-dialog-title-dialog').html('Error');
                    $('#dialog_text').html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    $(this).find('button.submitbutton').attr('disabled', '');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $msgdis = '<div class="login-box-error-small corners"><p>Error, '+errmsg+'</p></div>';
            $(errorselector).html($msgdis).slideDown('slow');
        }
        //make sure the form doesn't post
        return false;
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you add the session in autoload.php?

Comment: Yes right now the session in loded in autoload.php.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller in function `login_action()` remove `exit`. You stopped script so `$passstring` will never be set.

so this function should look like that:

```
function login_action(){
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $query = $this->login_model->check_login();
        if($query){
            $data = array(
                'adminid' => $query[0]['AdminID'],
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            print_r($this->session);
            //exit; <-- remove this
            //redirect('admin');
            $success = true;
            $success_redirect = true;
            $success_msg = site_url('admin');
            $error = false;
            $error_msg = '';            
        }else{
            $success = false;
            $success_redirect = false;
            $success_msg = site_url('admin');
            $error = true;
            $error_msg = 'Error, Wrong username or password!';
        }
        $passstring = array(
            'success' => $success,
            'success_msg' => $success_msg,
            'success_redirect' => $success_redirect,
            'error' => $error,
            'error_msg' => $error_msg
        );

        echo json_encode($passstring);
    }
```